# how to work with overflow property

Tags: css

Js Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ed4qz4a7/1/

i have `<div class="home" ><div/>` with the height of `666px` and i've got 2 images,  each image contains the height `666px` which means two images are containing `1332px` of height. i want the second image to be hidden beneath 1st image.

i was trying

```
<section class="home">
  <ul>
    <li class="img1"></li>
    <li class="img2"></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

CSS

```
 .home
 {
  height:666px;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
 }
```

Comment: Your example contains `min-height`, which is causing the issue. Use `height`: https://jsfiddle.net/tydch3bd/

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working, see demo here:

```
<section class="home">
  <ul>
    <li class="img1"><img src="http://placehold.it/666x666"></li>
    <li class="img2"><img src="http://placehold.it/666x666"></li>
  </ul>
</section>

 .home
 {
  height:666px;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
 }
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjbQom

Answer (score 1):

### Summary

The overflow property specifies whether to clip content, render scrollbars or just display content when it overflows its block level container.

Using the overflow property with a value different to visible (its default) will create a new block formatting context. This is technically necessary — if a float intersected with the scrolling element it would forcibly rewrap the content. The rewrap would happen after each scroll step, leading to a slow scrolling experience.

In order for the overflow property to have an effect, ***the block level container must either have a bounding height (height or max-height) or have white-space set to nowrap***.

```
Initial value   visible
Applies         to non-replaced block-level elements and non-replaced inline-block elements
Inherited       no
Media           visual
Computed value  as specified
Animatable      no
Canonical order the unique non-ambiguous order defined by the formal grammar
```

### Syntax

```
/* Content is not clipped */
overflow: visible;

/* Content is clipped, with no scrollbars */
overflow: hidden;

/* Content is clipped, with scrollbars */
overflow: scroll;

/* Let the browser decide */
overflow: auto;

/* Global values */
overflow: inherit;
overflow: initial;
overflow: unset;
```

### Values

> **visible**
>     Default value. Content is not clipped, it may be rendered outside the content box.
>
> **hidden**
>   The content is clipped and no scrollbars are provided.
>
> **scroll**
>   The content is clipped and desktop browsers use scrollbars, whether or not any content is clipped. This avoids any problem with scrollbars appearing and disappearing in a dynamic environment. Printers may print overflowing content.
>
> **auto**
>   Depends on the user agent. Desktop browsers like Firefox provide scrollbars if content overflows.

### Formal syntax

```
visible | hidden | scroll | auto
```

### Examples

**Method 01**

```
p {  
     width: 12em;
     height: 6em;
     border: dotted;
     overflow: visible; /* content is not clipped */ 
}
```

Output

[image: 01]

**Method 02**

```
p { overflow: hidden; /* no scrollbars are provided */ }
```

Output

[image: 02]

**Method 03**

```
p { overflow: scroll; /* always show scrollbars */ }
```

Output

[image: 03]

**Method 04**

```
p { overflow: auto; /* append scrollbars if necessary */ }
```

Output

[image: 04]

Some related attributes

1. [text-overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp)
2. [white-space](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)
3. [overflow-x](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp)
4. [overflow-y](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp)
5. [clip](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp)
6. [display](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Comment: @Daniel did you check this??

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 *
    {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    .home
    {
      min-height: 666px;
      max-width: 100%;
    }

        ul
        {
            position:absolute:
            list-style:none;
        }

        li
        {
          position: relative;
          float:left;
          width:100%;
          height:100%;
          background-size:cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-position: center center;
        }

    .img1
    {
      height: 666px;
      width: 100%;
      background-image: url('http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg');

    }
    .img2
    {
      background-image: url('http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg');
      display: none;
    }
```

Comment: I think he doesn't want that the second img isn't displayed. It should be behind the 1st img.

Answer (score 0):

In order to 'hide' an image behind another you want to set their position to absolute.

```
<section class="home">
  <ul>
    <li class="img1"><img src="http://placehold.it/666x666"></li>
    <li class="img2"><img src="http://placehold.it/666x666"></li>
  </ul>
</section>

ul{
  display: inline;
}

li{
  position: absolute;
}
```

You can fix the width and height of the `.home` container if you wish but I have left it out of my example for clarity of method.